is btrfs device remove the correct action?
I am not very confident with BTRFS. I have this situation in my server:
# findmnt -nt btrfs
/                         /dev/nvme0n1p9[/@]       btrfs  rw,relatime,ssd,discard=async,space_cache=v2,subvolid=256,subvol=/@
├─/home                   /dev/nvme0n1p9[/@home]   btrfs  rw,relatime,ssd,discard=async,space_cache=v2,subvolid=257,subvol=/@home
├─/var/log                /dev/nvme0n1p9[/@log]    btrfs  rw,relatime,ssd,discard=async,space_cache=v2,subvolid=259,subvol=/@log
├─/var/cache              /dev/nvme0n1p9[/@cache]  btrfs  rw,relatime,ssd,discard=async,space_cache=v2,subvolid=258,subvol=/@cache
├─/tmp                    /dev/nvme0n1p8           btrfs  rw,relatime,ssd,discard=async,space_cache=v2,subvolid=5,subvol=/
└─/var/lib                /dev/sda3                btrfs  rw,relatime,ssd,discard=async,space_cache=v2,subvolid=5,subvol=/
  └─/var/lib/docker/btrfs /dev/sda3[/docker/btrfs] btrfs  rw,relatime,ssd,discard=async,space_cache=v2,subvolid=5,subvol=/

and
btrfs filesystem show 
Label: none  uuid: 61825ab9-aad4-4790-a67d-83b1468d1a35
        Total devices 2 FS bytes used 267.38GiB
        devid    1 size 135.77GiB used 135.76GiB path /dev/nvme0n1p9
        devid    3 size 3.64TiB used 150.00GiB path /dev/sdb

Label: none  uuid: 7f4c063c-37d2-479b-8466-aef1f7a8122d
        Total devices 1 FS bytes used 14.56GiB
        devid    1 size 19.53GiB used 16.52GiB path /dev/nvme0n1p8

Label: none  uuid: 1efc28bc-f08e-49fc-8bac-1c5de861a4a6
        Total devices 1 FS bytes used 1004.81GiB
        devid    1 size 1.53TiB used 1.04TiB path /dev/sda3

So the question is: what exactly happens if I do:
# btrfs device remove /dev/sda3 /var/lib
Are data in /var/lib all moved to / filesystem keeping the same path?
I would expect it does it but I am not sure.
